# I failed to safely eject my USB drive and data became invisible… how do I get it back?

Tags: usb, data-recovery, gparted, usb-drive, drive

My USB was in the USB port and at the time I was copying something to my HDD I decided to cancel it. Immediately afterwards I decided to remove the USB but I forgot to press safe eject.

As a result of this, when I re-inserted my flash drive into the USB port, I saw one folder with some files in it which was one of the many folders I had on my USB, and `AUTORUN.INF` which wasn't there before. The rest of the files are gone.

The strange thing is that when I check the partition in Gparted it shows that my USB still have some files on it but when I decided to check for hidden files (CTRL+H) there was only one folder .Trash-1000. I also tried to recover some data via Gparted (GPart) but it didn't detect any partitions. According to Gparted the files are still there but I can't see them. I have also checked it on another distro and the results are the same. The file system on my flash drive is FAT32.

What happened to my files and how can I restore them?

Comment: Could you try to scan the drive with Testdisk and then report about its output? So we can get a more detailed overview of the situation. I will now flag this Q as a possible duplicate of another one which was about exFAT (not FAT32) but you can apply the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because the USB's FAT32 filesystem has the "Dirty" bit set.

To check:

1. Unplug the USB drive.
2. Wait 15 seconds.
3. Insert the USB drive.
4. Wait 15 seconds.
5. Issue the `dmesg` command, and read the last several lines. If the "Dirty" bit is set, you'll see a line similar (YMMV) to

   `FAT-fs (sdc): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.`

If this is the case, the `run fsck` step will be:

```
sudo fsck.vfat -w -y /dev/sdX
```

(replace `/dev/sdX` with your disk, and read `man fsck.vfat`)

When the `fsck.vfat` has finished, remove and re-insert the USB drive.

If `Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.` is not seen in the `dmesg` output, but it blathers on about `Mount on Windows, run chkdsk` then the above answer does not apply, and you must mount it on Windows.