# USB safely remove

Tags: usb-drive

A few days ago I removed a USB stick before clicking on **Safely remove** and since then the USB stick is **not recognizable to Ubuntu** also on Windows xp or Android on mobile phone.
I have tried to reboot Ubuntu with USB attached on a Laptop but no results.
**How to make USB recognizable** to UBUNTU 18.04.1 LTS ?

Comment: Are you able to see that usb in disk app in ubuntu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I failed to safely eject my USB drive and data became invisible… how do I get it back?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855798/i-failed-to-safely-eject-my-usb-drive-and-data-became-invisible-how-do-i-get-it)

Comment: Piyush Mhatre; i have tried to find the USB storage with **Disk startup** then with **Gnome disks**, **KDF**, **Mate disk analyzer** and with all of this 4 disk app i did not found any USB. Would you be more specific what name of disk app you are suggesting?

Comment: Pizza; here are two outputs of two commands i have entered in Terminal:   iu@iu-Inspiron-3542: dmesg
[ 6121.327449] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 4

Comment: Pizza: second command                                                                                   iu@iu-Inspiron-3542: fsck
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
/dev/sda1 is mounted.



WARNING!!!  The filesystem is mounted.   If you continue you ***WILL***
cause ***SEVERE*** filesystem damage.


Do you really want to continue<n>? no
check aborted.

Comment: Pizza: and after the warning message i did not continue forward . So what to do next in order to recognize USB storage?